# On loss of generality proving the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

In Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* the Schwarz inequality: $|(x,y)| \le ||x|| \  ||y||$ is proven in the following manner:

Put  $A = ||x||^2, B=|(x,y)|$ and $C = ||y||^2$. There is a complex number $\alpha$ such that $| \alpha| = 1 $ and $\alpha (y,x) = B$. For any real r, we then have:

$$(x-r\alpha y,x - r\alpha y) = (x,x) - r\alpha(y,x) - r\overline{\alpha}(x,y) + r^2(y,y).$$

The expression on the left is real and not negative. Hence:

$$A-2Br +Cr^2 \ge 0$$ for every real r. If $C = 0$, we must have $B = 0$. If $C >0$, take r = B/C and obtain $ B^2 \le AC $.

Could someone explain to me why there is no loss of generality when we take the complex number $\alpha$ such that $| \alpha| = 1 $ and $\alpha (y,x) = B$ ?

Did we not construct the inequality in order to get the result?

Comment: In that proof, do you make any restrictions on $x$ or $y$ when introducing $\alpha$? You are not trying to prove Cauchy-Schwarz for all $\alpha$, you are trying to prove it for all $x,y$, and to do this you use the fact that there exists an $\alpha$ with the given properties.

Comment: This is just a normalization.

Comment: Rudin can be just a little bit terse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are troubled that they implicitly assumed the existence of an $\alpha$ such that $\alpha\cdot (y,x)=B$; such an $\alpha$ always exists **provided that $(y,x)\neq 0$**. Simply let $\alpha = \frac{B}{(y,x)}$. Then
$$
|\alpha|=\frac{|B|}{|(y,x)|}=\frac{|(x,y)|}{|(y,x)|}=1
$$
So, the only loss of generality that occurs is that the above proof doesn't quite cover the case where $(y,x)=0$. However, the Schwarz inequality still holds in this case, and the proof is much easier.